# What is the reason for performing First level encoding on NetBIOS Names?

Tags: netbios

Reference: [RFC 1001](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1001.html#section-14.1)

In simple terms, each character is split into two parts based on its ASCII value, and each part is then added to A (0x41) to form two new characters.

For example, the character W corresponds to 0x57, which is split into 0x5 and 0x7. Each part is then added to 0x41, resulting in 0x46 and 0x48, which are F and H respectively.

Although this encoding process is designed to work in conjunction with DNS compression, it still results in a longer overall message length (from 16 to 32 bytes).

So, Why First level encoding is necessary in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* that it is to preserve compatibility with DNS software. As the spec says, NetBIOS names are always NUL-padded to 16 bytes, and their last byte is used to indicate the name type (i.e. is not an always ASCII character). Although DNS as a protocol *could* support labels containing NULs (it uses length-value encoding), clients and servers written in C and similar languages would likely have issues trying to resolve e.g. `Example PC\0\0\0\x03.example.com.` as they would typically expect NUL-terminated strings as input.